# React to duplicate unique key error in MongoDB's java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I am developing an application which uses MongoDB, and one of my fields must be unique. This field is calculated by the application based on another value in the DB. If I am running multiple instances of the application, however, I can imagine the applications calculating the same value.

In this case, I would like to catch the exception, recalculate the value, and try again. Unfortunately, the exception raised seems to be a simple MongoWriteException. It seems to me that the only way I will know that it is due to the duplicate key issue is based on the exception message, but parsing and making use of the message really doesn't feel right. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the [ErrorCategory](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/ErrorCategory.html) of the error inside the [MongoWriteException](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoWriteException.html) and confirm it was due to a duplicate key using `getCategory()`:

```
catch(MongoWriteException ex) {
    if(ex.getError().getCategory() == ErrorCategory.DUPLICATE_KEY) {
        //handle duplicate key error
    } else {
        //do something else...
    }
}
```